# Is it "When my time begins" or "When it's my time" etc.?

Tags: phrase-usage, expression-choice, colloquialisms, syntactic-analysis, metaphors

Can anyone please help me with the following sentence?

> Right now things may not be happening as per my wish but, **when my time starts / begins**, I will... (blah, blah)

I need help with alternatives for "when my time starts/ begins". I have also heard people using "when it's my day". It's pretty confusing for a non-native speaker like me.

Concrete example is as below:

> **When my time comes**, I will try and forgive those who reviled me, and focus my energy on self enhancement to finish what I had started.

---

Update

I want a positive, powerful and motivational statement to keep me going through difficult times. At the same time I am hopeful that soon things will change positively and when they do, I will not waste time thinking about how people treated me when I was not successful rather I will focus on my goal. So far I see there are 3 different meanings:

1. *When my time starts/begins*: refers to stopwatch / countdown.
2. *When my time comes/when its my time*: refers that somebody is dying
3. *When my day comes*: this would be illogical and literal translation of Hindi to English, I do not think this would make sense in English.

Anyway, Thank You friends.

Comment: You might also want to consider "When my time comes," but I think we will need more, and more concrete examples.

Comment: "When my time comes" is sometimes a euphemism for dying.  Example: "When my time comes, I want to have no regrets for how I lived my life."

Comment: In your update example, “When my time comes” can very easily be read to mean “When I’m dying,” so I think it’s important to specify what you want the phrase to convey.

Comment: Thank you ab2 and Shades, yes! exactly this is what has brought me to this beautiful website. I knew that somehow it conveys "somebody is dying". I want to convey the meaning in the sense that "now (due to less success) people may be looking down on me but, when (..and it will be) the time is positive, I will forgive those who reviled me. Please enlighten on this.

Comment: If you're question is answered in the comments, please *don't put this into the question.* you can answer your own question in the separate answer box below. make sure you properly cite who helped, using community wiki if possible.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning you seek is still slightly unclear, but I will answer now and revise/delete as you get closer to the meaning you want.

> **When my ship comes in**

Refers to that day that success finally catches up to you. It could mean that you got a spectacular job offer, you won the lottery, etc. You are now a success, most likely due to luck.

Comment: +1 and similar - *when (finally) the sun shines on me*...

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the answer in the Oxford Dictionary.
*(one's day) The most active or successful period of a person's life or career.
‘he had been a star in his day’.
So, I will need to change my sentence to:

> When it's my day, I will try and forgive those who reviled me, and focus my energy on self enhancement to finish what I had started.

I wanted to refer to success and the above meaning conveys it.
Thank you all.

Comment: The problem with this is that it’s too vague. This phrase is often said with an adjective attached, such as “my special day.” Otherwise it’s too similar to “when my day comes,” which is again too similar to “when my time comes”

Comment: Thanks, so what exactly do you propose should be done? According to Oxford Dictionary "One's Day" is not a single day, it's a time period, it should convey the meaning. Also I think I have given enough explanation for what kind of sentence I need. What would you use when you want to emphasize on the time period (in future) when things start happening according to your wish?

Comment: You're not completely incorrect. The phrase "Every dog has its day" comes to mind to back up your thinking. There's just something awkward about using "my day" in your example.

Comment: *When my [big moment](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/moment) arrives....*  OR *When I finally [make it big](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/make-it-big)...*

Comment: If my suggestions are helpful, you can include them in your answer.